# Calculate the time difference with next row based on a condition and grouping by ID in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The time difference with next row, grouping by ID, having condition>0 need to be calculated in pandas

input

```
ID          timestamp  Condition
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:27      23.33
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:33      13.26
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:39       5.71
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:45       0.00
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:51       0.00
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:57       0.00
aa  2023-1-5 06:46:15       0.00
aa  2023-1-5 06:46:21       0.00
aa  2023-1-5 06:46:27       2.18
aa  2023-1-5 06:46:33       0.00
aa  2023-1-5 06:46:39       4.10
aa  2023-1-5 06:46:45      21.73
aa  2023-1-5 06:46:51      33.79
```

Output:

timestamp_next |    time_diff_next(seconds) |

1/5/2023 6:33:33 |  6  |

1/5/2023 6:33:39 |  6 |

1/5/2023 6:46:27 |  768 |

```
| |

| |

| |

||

||
```

1/5/2023 6:46:39 | 12 |

```
||
```

1/5/2023 6:46:45 |  6 |

1/5/2023 6:46:51 |6 |

1/5/2023 6:46:57 | 6 |

Sample code

```
df2=df_input[(df_input['Condition']>0)]
       
df2['timestamp']= pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'])
df2['timestamp_next']=df2.groupby("id")["timestamp"].shift(-1)
df2['time_diff_next']=(df2['timestamp_next']-df2['timestamp'])/timedelta(seconds=1)

df_input=df_input.merge(df2[['id','timestamp','timestamp_next','time_diff_next']],how='left',on=['id','timestamp'])
```

I need to implement this code without creating new dataframe df2 as in above code

Comment: Please can you reformat your output. As I don't understand the result, I prefer leave untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['time_diff_next'] = (df.mask(df['Condition'].eq(0)).groupby('ID')['timestamp']
                          .transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds().shift(-1)))
print(df)

# Output
    ID           timestamp  Condition  time_diff_next
0   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:27      23.33             6.0
1   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:33      13.26             6.0
2   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:39       5.71           768.0
3   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:45       0.00             NaN
4   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:51       0.00             NaN
5   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:57       0.00             NaN
6   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:15       0.00             NaN
7   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:21       0.00             NaN
8   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:27       2.18            12.0
9   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:33       0.00             NaN
10  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:39       4.10             6.0
11  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:45      21.73             6.0
12  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:51      33.79             NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to compute `diff` or `shift` per group, you need to use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to avoid side effects. [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) on the filtered DataFrame for non-null Condition seems appropriate here.

Here is one suggestion to work in the original DataFrame:

```
m = df['Condition'].gt(0)
df['time_diff_next(seconds)'] = (df[m].groupby('ID')['timestamp']
                                 .diff().dt.total_seconds()
                                )
```

Another approach to avoid a `groupby` might be to [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) but I expect performance to be quite bad:

```
df.merge(df[m].pivot(index='timestamp', columns='ID', values='timestamp'
                    ).diff().unstack().rename('time_diff_next(seconds)'),
         left_on=['ID', 'timestamp'], right_index=True, how='left')
```

Output:

```
    ID           timestamp  Condition  time_diff_next(seconds)
0   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:27      23.33                      NaN
1   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:33      13.26                      6.0
2   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:39       5.71                      6.0
3   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:45       0.00                      NaN
4   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:51       0.00                      NaN
5   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:57       0.00                      NaN
6   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:15       0.00                      NaN
7   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:21       0.00                      NaN
8   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:27       2.18                    768.0
9   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:33       0.00                      NaN
10  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:39       4.10                     12.0
11  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:45      21.73                      6.0
12  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:51      33.79                      6.0
```

*NB. if you want to get the diff shifter up, use `diff(-1)` and negate the output:*

```
m = df['Condition'].gt(0)
df['time_diff_next(seconds)'] = (-df[m].groupby('ID')['timestamp']
                                 .diff(-1).dt.total_seconds()
                                 )
```

Output:

```
    ID           timestamp  Condition  time_diff_next(seconds)
0   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:27      23.33                      6.0
1   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:33      13.26                      6.0
2   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:39       5.71                    768.0
3   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:45       0.00                      NaN
4   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:51       0.00                      NaN
5   aa 2023-01-05 06:33:57       0.00                      NaN
6   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:15       0.00                      NaN
7   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:21       0.00                      NaN
8   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:27       2.18                     12.0
9   aa 2023-01-05 06:46:33       0.00                      NaN
10  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:39       4.10                      6.0
11  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:45      21.73                      6.0
12  aa 2023-01-05 06:46:51      33.79                      NaN
```

Comment: Ingenious the `-diff(-1)`!